# R: using strsplit in a tibble column

Tags: r, tibble, strsplit

I have a tibble and in one of the columns are strings. They are names of instruments that respondents to a survey said they played. I would like to capture each instrument as it's own separate string. Values in this column range from one single string like guitar, to more complex answers: Sing, Drums/Percussion, Piano/Keyboard... etc
I have tried something like this:

```
options <- strsplit(survey$instruments_list, "\\, | \\/ | ")
```

unfortunately the output still has the / character between several strings.

also as a final problem, one of the respondents answered with an incredibly long winded answer separated by multiple spaces and I just want the instrument, not their life story.

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thank you! 
edit:
results of dput(head(survey))

```
structure(list(time_submitted = c("8/27/19 20:22", "8/29/19 12:15", 
"8/28/19 19:33", "8/29/19 16:25", "8/27/19 15:40", "8/27/19 22:59"
), pseudonym_generator = c("Fake rapper name generator", "Fake band name generator", 
"Fake band name generator", "Fake band name generator", "Fake band name generator", 
"Fake band name generator"), pseudonym = c("Lord Los Angeles", 
"Heroes War", "Puppets War", "West Magic", "Eller Angel", "Trace Stripes"
), sex = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), academic_major = c("Computer Science", 
"Computer Science", "Math", "Computer Science", "Computer Science", 
"Computer Science"), academic_level = c("Senior", "Junior", "Senior", 
"Junior", "Senior", "Senior"), year_born = c(1994, 1997, 1996, 
1999, 1998, 1986), instrument_list = c("Rap", "Guitar", "Guitar", 
"Trumpet", "Piano/Keyboards, Ukulele", NA), favorite_song_artist = c("40 crew", 
"Arctic Monkeys", "Avatar", "Ben Folds", "blink-182", "brian jonestown massacre / sarabeth tucek"
), favorite_song = c("Not Enough", "Arabella", "The Eagle Has Landed", 
"Still", "She's Out Of Her Mind", "Seer"), favorite_song_link = c("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uITuGZKljgQ", 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jn6-TItCazo", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4p6GWewmTYQ", 
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShBzUK4rnI8", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krpm0v_486k", 
"https://youtu.be/C-XT7DZsNP8")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking. I am pretty new to R.

Comment: stackoverflow says it is too long

Comment: so you want to `instrument_list` into different columns or rows ?

Comment: sorry I should have declared my end goal. I am going to make a new tibble, with the columns: pseudonym and then a column for each instrument listed in instruments_list. So I want all the instruments given in instruments_list to have their own column and then an observation of either plays or does not play, something like that, for each pseudonym.

Comment: Do you mean something like `strsplit(survey$instrument_list, "[,/]")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
survey %>%
  transmute(pseudonym, inst = strsplit(instrument_list, "[,/]")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(inst)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(inst = trimws(inst), plays = TRUE) %>%
  spread(inst, plays) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-pseudonym), Negate(is.na))
# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#   pseudonym        Guitar Keyboards Piano Rap   Trumpet Ukulele
#   <chr>            <lgl>  <lgl>     <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>   <lgl>  
# 1 Eller Angel      FALSE  TRUE      TRUE  FALSE FALSE   TRUE   
# 2 Heroes War       TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 3 Lord Los Angeles FALSE  FALSE     FALSE TRUE  FALSE   FALSE  
# 4 Puppets War      TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 5 West Magic       FALSE  FALSE     FALSE FALSE TRUE    FALSE
```

---

It's not hard to combine multiple instruments into single categories. I'll adapt one of your instruments to demonstrate.

One method is with `case_when`, perhaps the more direct/literal of the two methods:

```r
survey %>%
  mutate(instrument_list = if_else(grepl("Lord", pseudonym), "Electric Guitar", instrument_list)) %>%
  transmute(pseudonym, inst = strsplit(instrument_list, "[,/]")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(inst)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(inst = trimws(inst), plays = TRUE) %>%
  spread(inst, plays) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-pseudonym), Negate(is.na))
# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#   pseudonym        `Electric Guitar` Guitar Keyboards Piano Trumpet Ukulele
#   <chr>            <lgl>             <lgl>  <lgl>     <lgl> <lgl>   <lgl>  
# 1 Eller Angel      FALSE             FALSE  TRUE      TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   
# 2 Heroes War       FALSE             TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 3 Lord Los Angeles TRUE              FALSE  FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 4 Puppets War      FALSE             TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 5 West Magic       FALSE             FALSE  FALSE     FALSE TRUE    FALSE  

survey %>%
  mutate(instrument_list = if_else(grepl("Lord", pseudonym), "Electric Guitar", instrument_list)) %>%
  transmute(pseudonym, inst = strsplit(instrument_list, "[,/]")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(inst)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(
    inst = case_when(
      grepl("\\bPiano\\b", inst, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Piano",
      grepl("\\bUkelete\\b", inst, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Ukelele",
      grepl("\\bGuitar\\b", inst, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Guitar",
      TRUE ~ trimws(inst)),
    plays = TRUE,
  ) %>%
  spread(inst, plays) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-pseudonym), Negate(is.na))
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   pseudonym        Guitar Keyboards Piano Trumpet Ukulele
#   <chr>            <lgl>  <lgl>     <lgl> <lgl>   <lgl>  
# 1 Eller Angel      FALSE  TRUE      TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   
# 2 Heroes War       TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 3 Lord Los Angeles TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 4 Puppets War      TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 5 West Magic       FALSE  FALSE     FALSE TRUE    FALSE
```

Another method (if you have many more) is to merge/join in a frame. One advantage to this is that it can be very specific and include very-different instruments (where regex might be more than you want to handle). One disadvantage is that it can be too specific ... it does not join in mis-spellings or case differences, for instance.

```r
gen_inst <- tibble::tribble(
  ~inst, ~newinst
 ,"Electric Guitar", "Guitar"
 ,"Electric Bass"  , "Guitar"
 ,"Electric Piano" , "Piano"
 ,"Pipe Organ"     , "Piano"
)

survey %>%
  mutate(instrument_list = if_else(grepl("Lord", pseudonym), "Electric Guitar", instrument_list)) %>%
  transmute(pseudonym, inst = strsplit(instrument_list, "[,/]")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(inst)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  left_join(gen_inst, by = "inst") %>%
  mutate(
    inst = if_else(is.na(newinst), trimws(inst), newinst),
    plays = TRUE
  ) %>%
  select(-newinst) %>%
  spread(inst, plays) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-pseudonym), Negate(is.na))
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
#   pseudonym        Guitar Keyboards Piano Trumpet Ukulele
#   <chr>            <lgl>  <lgl>     <lgl> <lgl>   <lgl>  
# 1 Eller Angel      FALSE  TRUE      TRUE  FALSE   TRUE   
# 2 Heroes War       TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 3 Lord Los Angeles TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 4 Puppets War      TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
# 5 West Magic       FALSE  FALSE     FALSE TRUE    FALSE
```

Comment: thank you! I really liked this one as it included some functions I had seen before in a previous statistics class.

Comment: `Negate` one is classic

Comment: if I could ask on more question, I have two columns for ukulele (Ukulele and Elementary Ukulele) and piano (piano and a very long answer involving piano) I would like to merge those two columns for Ukulele into one Ukulele column, same regarding piano. I have tried unite and unite_ but neither compiled. thank you

Comment: also, apologies for not selecting an answer earlier.

Comment: In the `mutate` after `unnest`, try something like `inst = if_else(grepl("Piano", inst), "Piano", inst)` and another for ukelele.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`

```
output <- splitstackshape::cSplit_e(survey, "instrument_list", type = "character", 
                 fill = 0, sep=",|/", fixed = FALSE)

output[12:17]
#  instrument_list_Guitar instrument_list_Keyboards instrument_list_Piano
#1                      0                         0                     0
#2                      1                         0                     0
#3                      1                         0                     0
#4                      0                         0                     0
#5                      0                         1                     1
#6                      0                         0                     0

#  instrument_list_Rap instrument_list_Trumpet instrument_list_Ukulele
#1                   1                       0                       0
#2                   0                       0                       0
#3                   0                       0                       0
#4                   0                       1                       0
#5                   0                       0                       1
#6                   0                       0                       0
```

Here 1 in the column represents the instrument is played and 0 means it is not played.

Comment: these are both great techniques!! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Not wildly different from the other answers, but here's one using some `tidyr` conveniences. `separate_rows` splits strings and unnests them in one call; if you include an optional `\\s` in the regex, spaces in `", "` will be included in the separator so you can skip trimming whitespace. Adding a dummy variable gives a value to populate the instrument columns, and the `NA`s get filled in with 0.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

survey_wide <- survey %>%
  select(pseudonym, instrument_list) %>%
  separate_rows(instrument_list, sep = "(\\,|\\/)\\s?") %>%
  filter(!is.na(instrument_list)) %>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  spread(key = instrument_list, value = dummy, fill = 0) 

survey_wide
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>   pseudonym        Guitar Keyboards Piano   Rap Trumpet Ukulele
#>   <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Eller Angel           0         1     1     0       0       1
#> 2 Heroes War            1         0     0     0       0       0
#> 3 Lord Los Angeles      0         0     0     1       0       0
#> 4 Puppets War           1         0     0     0       0       0
#> 5 West Magic            0         0     0     0       1       0
```

An additional step if you need booleans instead of numbers:

```r
survey_wide %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-pseudonym), as.logical)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>   pseudonym        Guitar Keyboards Piano Rap   Trumpet Ukulele
#>   <chr>            <lgl>  <lgl>     <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>   <lgl>  
#> 1 Eller Angel      FALSE  TRUE      TRUE  FALSE FALSE   TRUE   
#> 2 Heroes War       TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
#> 3 Lord Los Angeles FALSE  FALSE     FALSE TRUE  FALSE   FALSE  
#> 4 Puppets War      TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE  
#> 5 West Magic       FALSE  FALSE     FALSE FALSE TRUE    FALSE
```